# How Can I Make Perfect Acute Triangle with for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Just for playing I tried to write a program so I can make a acute triangle with using a for loop, so my out put will like this:

```
                 0
                1  1
               2  2  2
              3  3  3  3
             4  4  4  4  4
            5  5  5  5  5  5
           6  6  6  6  6  6  6
          7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
         8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
        9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
```

but when I want to go more than 10 my acute triangle gets messed up like this:

```
                 0
                1  1
               2  2  2
              3  3  3  3
             4  4  4  4  4
            5  5  5  5  5  5
           6  6  6  6  6  6  6
          7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
         8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
        9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
       10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10


12           12           12           12           12           12           12           12           12           12           12           12           12
```

My code is as follows

```
public class Triangel {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 20; k > i - 1; k--) {
                if (i =< 9) {
                    System.out.print("           " + (20 - i));
                } else if (i > 9) {
                    System.out.print( "  "+(20 - i));
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can make it perfect acute triangle when I wanna print after 9?

Note: I thought that the if statement would help, but it seems it does not.

Comment: You really should be able to think about this one by yourself.

Comment: It is just the way of printing that is creating the difference. You can put more space characters to make it look like an acute triangle.

Comment: Each digit in screen is confined to a specific number of pixels. When you want a number greater than 9 meaning you are using 2 digits then this agreement is broken so there is no symmetry in the output. So what did you expected?

Comment: @Eypros did you see my if statements part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just Change Inner for loop* : here for `k=i-1` as you are checking for `i>9` and `i<9` so 11 will be excluded. *I guess you are trying to manage space between two digit and one digit number.* But you can just use single for `i<=10` and double space for `i>10`

```
       for (int k = 20; k > i - 1; k--) {
            if (i <= 10) {
                System.out.print(" "+(20 - i));//Single Space
            } else if (i > 10) {
                System.out.print("  "+(20 - i));//Double Space
            }
        }
```

*NOTE:This triangle may look weird little bit*

Comment: thank u and I take a look at later. could you please tell what you mean this triangle may look weird little bit? what do u think about my approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you're printing single digits you can put a space after each one to match the length of the double digits. This way you will be able to go to 99.

Applying this method on a larger scale simply means that you have to do a check before your main cycles, which will tell you how long is the largest number and the compensate the lenght difference if shorter numbers with spaces.

Comment: what you mean about single digits?

Comment: @kickbuttowski single digits are 0-9 double are 10-99 and so on.. character length of the number

Answer (score 0):

Should work with any amout of rows. Haven't tested with thousands though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxRows = 14;
    int spaces = String.valueOf(maxRows).length();

    for (int i = 1; i <= maxRows; i++) {            // for each row
        for (int j = 1; j <= maxRows - i; j++) {    // add spaces to the left
            for (int l = 1; l <= spaces; l++) {     // according to number of digits
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {              // for each column
            System.out.print(i);
            for (int l = String.valueOf(i).length(); l <= spaces * 2 - 1; l++) {    // add spaces inbetween
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
}
```

Comment: k thank u. I'll take a look at later. could u plz run my code too and tell what's going on?

Comment: in your if statement you are missing the case `i == 9`. That's why it writes an empty line. Anything else you want to know?