# How to make a pyramid using astersik in Java?

Tags: java

Good day guys! So I'm self learning java right now. And one of the exercises I'm answering now is creating a program Pyramid.java that takes an input N and prints a 
pyramid whose each side is of length N, like the one below: My problem is that everytime I put an input on the command line, the 3 asterisk in the middle don't appear.

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

Here's my code

```
 public class D2Q6 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int k = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N-i; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print("*");
        if(i > 1) {
            if(i == N) {
                for(int j = 0; j < i-1; j++)
                    System.out.print(" *");
            }
            else {
                for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                k = k+2;
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is a **classic** programming exercise. There are answers for this [all over the place](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Beginning_exercises#Loops).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Make Perfect Acute Triangle with for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156468/how-can-i-make-perfect-acute-triangle-with-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to execute your program through eclipse or some editor with its own console. The issue might not be with the program, but with the font (type and size) used in console.

Try running the program in DOS prompt, and you might be able to see your desired outcome.

```
public class PrintPyramidStar
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int c = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < 8; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= c; k++)
            {
                if (k % 2 == 0)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            c += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Above is a random star program I picked using search. Running the same via eclipse console gave me skewed triangle, wherein running the same via windows command prompt gave me a perfect triangle.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I stepped through your program in Eclipse and thought the problem might be here. Currently this is printing a blank space.

```
        else {
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            k = k+2;
            System.out.print("*");
        }
```

If you change it to the below, it prints solid asterisk then an extra one at the end;

```
        else {
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            k = k+2;
            System.out.print("*");
        }
```

However I assume that you are going for a '* * *' kind of thing, but hopefully that narrows it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating two methods, one to get the spaces and one to get the asterisks. Something like,

```
private static String getNSpaces(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
private static String getNAsterisks(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append('*');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then your `main` method can be as simple as -

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    System.out.print(getNSpaces(N - i));
    System.out.println(getNAsterisks(i));
}
```

When I run the above with `N` equal to `5` I get

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post an alternative, brief approach to this common programming exercise.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(pyramid(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
}

public static String pyramid(int size) {
    return line(size, size);
}

public static String line(int max, int size) {
     return size < 1 ? "" : line(max, size - 1) + copies(" ", max - size) + copies("* ", size) + '\n';
}

public static String copies(String s, int size) {
    return size < 1 ? "" : String.formatîui("%0" + size + "d", 0).replace("0", s);
}
```

[See live demo](http://rextester.com/TYHX72999)

This uses recursion and breaks the code up into meaningful methods that each have their own task that is accomplished in one line.

This is not a high performance solution, but would be fast enough for moderate sizes. It is written for readability and method cohesion.